# What is the best way to handling error that returned from OS APIs in library?

Tags: c, error-handling, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I have create a library that will used by other developer in my company. But, I don't known how to return error with efficient. If I create the custom error codes that will return from my library, I don't known what to return when OS APIs (CreateFile, open etc.) has failed in my library. If I return `OPEN_FILE_FAILED` when `CreateFile` return an error, the problem is the caller will unable to known what the cause that make unable to open file.

If I return system error code instead, How to deal when my library need the error codes that is not defined by system?

My library are cross-platform.

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your lib's functions receives an error by the OS return that to the caller.

If the lib's functions fail due to a lib specific error condition return an error code defined specifically for this lib.

Along all this document each possible error your lib's function could possibly return also mentioning the concept (like fox example this above one) behind it.

Comment: If my `OPEN_FILE_FAILED` equal to 1 and OS have `ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION` equal to 1, how the caller will distinguish the source of error in this situation?

Comment: @PuttaKhunchalee: If your lib's fucntion receives an `ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION` do return exactly this error code to the caller. Do **only** return lib specific error codes if you have a lib **internal** issue to indicate.